# Definition of HEP correct?

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Algebraic Topology (Allen Hatcher, pg 14) I read a definition of
HEP:

---

...Suppose one is given a map $f_{0}:X\rightarrow Y$,
and on a subspace $A\subset X$ one is also given a homotopy $f_{t}:A\rightarrow Y$
of $f_{0}\mid A$ that one would like to extend to a homotopy $f_{t}:X\rightarrow Y$
of the given $f_{0}$. If the pair $\left(X,A\right)$ is such that
this extension problem can always be solved, one says that $\left(X,A\right)$
has the homotopy extension property. Thus $\left(X,A\right)$ has
the homotopy extension property if every map $X\times\left\{ 0\right\} \cup A\times I\rightarrow Y$
can be extended to a map $X\times I\rightarrow Y$.

---

I have the impression
that this conclusion is not correct. We have a map $g_{0}:X\times\left\{ 0\right\} \rightarrow Y$
with $\left(x,0\right)\mapsto f\left(x\right)$ and a map $G:A\times I\rightarrow Y$
with $\left(a,t\right)\mapsto f_{t}\left(a\right)$, but that will
only lead to a map $X\times\left\{ 0\right\} \cup A\times I\rightarrow Y$
under the extra condition that the two sets $X\times\left\{ 0\right\} $
and $A\times I$ have the so-called gluing-property. This will indeed
be the case if $A$ is closed but what if that is not so? Am I overlooking
something?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible to define $H : X \times \{0\} \cup A\times I \rightarrow Y$ by $H = g_0 \cup G$, considering $g_0$ and $G$ as set of pairs? We know that $g_0$ and $G(\cdot, 0)$ coincide so that it yields indeed a function.

Comment: It indeed yields a function, but not necessarily a continuous one. In the definition of Hatcher 'map' is equivalent to 'continuous function'.

Comment: You do not have the updated version of chapter 0. You can download it at [his homepage](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html). In the corrected text, he refers to Appendix, where you find a proof that a pair of maps can be glued to a continuous map if $A\times I\cup X\times\{0\}$ is a retract of $X\times I$ (which again is a consequence of every map from there being extendible to $X\times I$.)

Comment: Thank you very much for this enlightening answer.